# N keys and N locks at once

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

There are $N$ keys and $N$ locks. We test all keys at once.

What is the probability that $k$ keys are correctly matched to $k$ locks ($k \leq n$)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And... do we test all keys in the first lock?  Do we test at most one key per lock? What strategy do we follow when testing keys?

Comment: Your problem is basically this: https://probabilityandstats.wordpress.com/2010/05/02/more-about-the-matching-problem/.

Comment: @JMoravitz One key is tested per lock!

Comment: Then see my answer below.  Had we tested every key in the first lock, then the probability of getting $1$ correct would have been precisely $1$ while the probability of getting a number different than $1$ correct would have been precisely $0$, highlighting how the wording of the question can change the answer.  If we were to try keys in the first lock until we found a match, then move on to trying the next lock with the remaining keys until finding a match and so on, then we would get yet another answer.

Answer (score 4):

The number of permutations in $S_n$ which have $k$ fixed points will be $\binom{n}{k}\cdot !(n-k)$ where the subfactorial symbol $!r$ is in reference to the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $r$ objects.

Assuming that exactly one key is tested per lock, we have then a probability getting exactly $k$ of the matching keys to their corresponding locks as being

$$\dfrac{!(n-k)\binom{n}{k}}{n!}$$